# Taking in Command Line Arguments and Processes

Tags: c, operating-system

Take in command line arguments like so "program /path_name -l" and create both a parent and child process. Fork needs to be used to create the child and the child should replace itself using one of the exec commands. The parent process needs to wait for the child to finish and receive the exit status, then use the exit status to determine if the program exited normally and if the process was killed by some signal. I'm having an issue where my program always gets an exit status of 1. I'm not sure I'm doing the whole command line thing correctly.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1){
      perror("Fork Failure");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    else if ( pid == 0 ){
       execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int status;

    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    if ( WIFEXITED(status) ){
        int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        printf("Exit status is %d\n", exit_status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you expect exit status to be? On POSIX system value of `EXIT_FAILURE` is `1` and your child is returning that which is why you get exit status of `1`. See [GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html). If you want some custom exit status, in the `if (pid ==0)` condition, return something else. For example, `return 123;` would give you an exit status of `123`.

Comment: @Mihir hi! I made a really simple program to test that this was working, the program just returned the number 50 and if I understand correctly if I used that test file for this then the exit status of the child should read 50? I'm not entirely sure I understand how it works

Comment: To make it simple, `fork()` would make a copy of the program you are running from the place where you called it. So after the instant you called `fork`, 2 processes are running the same code. But in the parent, `fork()` would return pid of child whereas in child `fork` would have returned `0`. So the condition `if(pid==0)` is true in child and false in parent. Child enters that conditions and only if `execvp()` fails, you `return` would get executed. Otherwise `execvp` would replace your child process and your parent will receive exit status from the execd process.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you are using `exec` while writing my first comment.

Comment: Suppose you passed argument as `/bin/ls` which is the executable file for `ls` command, `execvp` would execute that and your parent will receive exit status of `ls`. If `ls` succeeded, your parent shall print `0` exit status. For testing purposes, you can try passing any arbitrary argument like `abc`(assuming that doesn't exists in your system) to you executable. As no `abc` exists, `execvp` would fail and your `return` statement would terminate the child instead.

Comment: @Mihir I see! So as I've written it my code isn't broken, I was just understanding it incorrectly? When I pass in the argument /bin/ls it returns an exit status of 0! I was concerned that for the task I was not getting the argument correctly for exec

Comment: @Mihir So now I need to have the parent use this exit status to determine if the program exited normally or if it was by some signal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200276/discussion-between-mihir-and-logan).

Comment: regarding: `execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
       return EXIT_FAILURE;`  This fails to inform the user of what failed.  Suggest: `execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);  perror( "execvp failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` as this will output to `stderr`, both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the failure occurred.

Comment: What command line arguments are you passing ? Just passing 'ls' works OK, returning status of 0.